# Is it possible to place a WordPress widget into the main page layout?

Tags: plugins

As the question suggests, can a widget be placed with the main body of a page rather than in a side-column?

I guess this is plugin-specific but generally, if the functionality is placed on a side-bar then does that "restrict" it to that section of the layout?

Comment: With `the_widget()` function you can put a widget anywhere, not just in a registered sidebar (widget area), https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_widget/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

of course you can, you can place widgets wherever you want in your page:

1. Define them in a callback function in your functions.php file which calls the `register_sidebar()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_sidebar/), and then hook that callback to the 'widgets_init' action hook, also in your functions.php file.
2. On the page where you wanna use it, wherever you wanna use it, print the widget with this code, by using the value you specified as the 'id' parameter when calling `register_sidebar()` in your callback:

```
<?php if ( dynamic_sidebar( 'id_of_ur_widget' ) ) : else : endif; ?>
```

Don't get distracted by the name of the function, `register_sidebar` doesn't mean that your widget is a sidebar, it's just the not-so-smartly chosen name of the wp function you use to create a custom widget.

Comment: who downvoted this and why...

Comment: honestly, if your question is not worthy of a being asked in an MIT Intellectual Debate then you get down-voted. There are increasing amounts of Trolls that just downvote for the sake of it. There is zero wrong with my question - it's a legitimate question asked by someone who doesn't know.

My question causes no offensive, no harm and has more benefits than negatives yet some idiot just comes around and downvotes. It's the crappy side to StackExchange in my view.

Comment: yeh me neither I didn't really understand why your question got downvoted (nor my answer..). Problem is that this is related to reputation changes etc., guess the problem is that you can earn "profile badges" by downvoting people's answers / questions, which may encourage people to blindly downvote. Maybe they should remove these kind of badge rewards.. Anyway, glad I could help u out! :) (upvoted your question, btw ;))